# Digital signature in PHP

Tags: php

Could someone please explain how to implement a "digital signature" in PHP. I've tried hard to find an answer myself, but have had little success so far.

Comment: you will have to give more information on what your are trying to accomplish. digital signature is a somewhat vague term.

Comment: tq for your respone, i am developing web base application using php, my project how people can approve a online form using digital signature. i have read about Cosign, you have any idea about it?

Comment: depending on the nature of the documents and your jurisdiction, a digital signature may or may not be binding.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a pro-forma answer since you have an overly unspecific inquiry anyway:

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/document", $text);
exec("gpg --clearsign /tmp/document");
$signed_text = file_get_contents("/tmp/document.asc");
```

Usually you want to add a `--keyring` option too. For more complex operations you can use the PHP extension for GPG as shown in this article: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3753

Comment: Hi the link in the answer is  not working.It will be very helpfull if it make working or provides other similar links

Comment: @RenjithKN: You can just use the web archive or google cache in such cases. Link works for me.